# Kotlin Coroutine Flow: How to get the first item from a flow (i.e. file metadata) and pass the remaining items as a content flow?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

I am using Kotlin Coroutines and Flow for a library that uploads files to Azure Blob Storage.  The flow consists of a metadata object followed by file content block objects.  I cannot figure out how to extract the metadata object, which contains the size, name, etc of the file, and then pass the remaining items in the flow as a Flow to Azure.  When I try filter these two kinds of objects from the flow, I get an error saying that a flow cannot be collected more than one time...  I am missing some concept and hope that you can help me.

Here are my latest attempts...

(1) The error makes sense in the following code since the blobMetadata is being collected and
the file content upload will be collected in the myUploadBlobAsync() method.  However,
the documentation says that using .filter results in new flows being created, so I thought
this code would work.

```
suspend fun uploadFile(requests: Flow<UploadFileRequest>): UploadFileResponse {

    // Materialize the file's metadata from the head of the Flow.
    var blobMetadata: BlobMetadata = BlobMetadata.getDefaultInstance()
    requests.filter { it.hasBlobMetadata() }.collect { blobMetadata = it.blobMetadata }

    // Send the remaining items in the Flow to Azure for the blob's content.  Use the 
    // metadata, above, to complete the request.
    val response = myUploadBlobAsync(
        containerName,
        blobPathAndFilename,
        requests.filter { it.hasFile() }.map { it.file.content.asReadOnlyByteBuffer() },
        metadata
    ).toUploadFileResponse()
}
```

(2) Using a SharedFlow as a bus.  With this code, I can provide separate Flows to the blobMetadata and file content processing, which seems like the way to go.  However, the code seems to do nothing.

```
val bus = BroadcastUploadFileRequestBus()
var blobMetadata = BlobMetadata.getDefaultInstance()

requests.map { request ->
    bus.postRequest(request)
}

bus.request.collect {
    if (it.hasBlobMetadata()) {
        blobMetadata = it.blobMetadata
    }
}

val response = myUploadBlobAsync(
        containerName,
        blobPathAndFilename,
        bus.request.filter { it.hasFile() }.map { it.file.content.asReadOnlyByteBuffer() },
        metadata
    ).toUploadFileResponse(tenantId)
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong with the `SharedFlow` approach given that it's hidden away in `BroadcastUploadFileRequestBus`.

Comment: Also your use case is a bit strange in one respect: on the one hand, you want the blobmetadata right away (~synchronously), but on the other hand, you want an (unconsumed) asynchronous flow of requests. Would a list of requests be ok instead of flow? Or, would a `Flow` or `StateFlow` for the metadata be ok?

Answer (score 2):

#### The problems

The `SharedFlow` is stuck for multiple reasons.

1. `bus.request.collect {}` is never stopped because a `SharedFlow` never ends. If you only really want the first element, you should rather use:

```kotlin
blobMetadata = bus.request.first { it.hasBlobMetadata() }
```

2. Even with this fix, the first event will never come, because `requests.map{}` doesn't do anything as long as the mapped flow is not consumed. So you most likely want to `collect` it instead of `map`, and if you want this collection to happen concurrently, you'll need to start a new coroutine to do this mapping.
   Note that there is a shortcut for this: `requests.shareIn(someCoroutineScope)`

Another more conceptual problem: on the one hand, you want the `blobmetadata` right away (~synchronously), but on the other hand, you want a cold flow of "contents", and both of these come from the same cold flow of requests.

Despite the previous fixes, your flow of "content" could miss all events because the `SharedFlow` may emit everything before your consumer starts collecting it.

#### Possible solutions

If you do need a cold flow, I see 2 possible solutions:

1. keep this flow of requests, and extract the first element's metadata at the same time you collect the rest (in `uploadBlobAsync`), so that you can actually process everything during one collection of the requests flow.
2. if you really want to abstract this mechanism away, you can transform the flow of requests into a new flow of content, where every element has the metadata attached to it. All this needs to happen *within* the flow's body (to stay cold):

```kotlin
data class UploadFileRequestWithMeta(
    val blobMetadata: BlobMetadata,
    val uploadRequest: UploadFileRequest,
)

fun Flow<UploadFileRequest>.withMeta(): Flow<UploadFileRequestWithMeta> = flow {
    var meta = BlobMetadata.getDefaultInstance()
    collect { r ->
        when {
            r.hasMetadata() -> meta = r.blobMetadata
            r.hasFile() -> emit(UploadFileRequestWithMeta(meta, r.file.content.asReadOnlyByteBuffer()))
        }
    }
}

suspend fun uploadFile(requests: Flow<UploadFileRequest>): UploadFileResponse {
    return myUploadBlobAsync(requests.withMeta()).toUploadFileResponse()
}
```

(as you can see, I'd rather go with option 1, otherwise what's the point of `uploadFile`?)

It all depends on the API you want to use once you have this "contents flow".
Can you explain how it looks like?

Comment: Hi Joffrey, Thank you very much for your response and questions.  The context for my posting is that I am using grpc-kotlin.  The client reads a file, asynchronously, and emits the metadata and content to a Flow to the server.  So, this is really a cold-flow use case and a good application of a Flow rather than the SharedFlow.  Grpc permits a union in each message that is sent in the Flow, so the server can distinguish the single metadata message from the content messages.

Comment: I think that I've implemented a good solution...  Scenario: Client sends metadata and blocks of file content to a grpc server.  The server collects the metadata and uses it to call the SDK's upload method.  The server collects the blocks on content, converts the flow to a flux, and passes it to the SDK.  My mock up seems to work, but I need to wire it up with the real Azure Blob SDK to see if all is well...

Comment: I've updated the original posting with the solution code...

Comment: *this is really a cold-flow use case* - if this is the case, then you can't read the metadata and the contents at different moments. Something hot needs to read the contents events after reading the metadata if you want these metadata right away. But we can change this, you may not need the metadata right away like this. See my suggested solutions, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the following code in the grpc server and it is working properly. It would be interesting to learn whether others can provide improvements to it. Hopefully, it will be helpful to others... Basically, the server collects the Flow from the client. The server saves the blobMetadata, and builds a new flow from the blocks of file content from the original flow. This Flow is passed to the SDK's upload method after conversion to a Flux via .asFlux().

```
        var blobMetadata: BlobMetadata = BlobMetadata.getDefaultInstance()
        var counter = 0L
        var sdkCounter = 0L
        val contentFlow = flow {
            requests.collect { request ->
                when {
                    // Assumes that the BlobMetadata always arrives before the file's content.
                    request.hasBlobMetadata() -> {
                        println("*** Received BlobMetadata at the server")
                        blobMetadata = request.blobMetadata
                    }
                    request.hasFile() -> {
                        println("Block(${++counter}) Received at the server")
                        emit(request.file.content.asReadOnlyByteBuffer())
                    }
                    else -> throw Exception("OUCH!")
                }
            }
        }
        // Send the new flow to our uploading method, which uses
        // the Azure Blob Storage SDK for Java v12
        val response = uploadBlobAsync(          
            blobMetadata.containerName,
            blobMetadata.blobPathAndFilename,
            contentFlow,
            blobMetadata.metadata
        ).toUploadFileResponse()
```

Comment: I don't quite get how this can possibly work as you expect. Because `contentFlow` is cold, the lambda that defines it is not called before the call to `uploadBlobAsync`. But you're expecting `blobMetadata` to be already set when you make the call to `uploadBlobAsync`. IMO the metadata 
you pass willl always be default here.